# edited and reversed changes on .htaccess - site starts redirecting to .comindex.php/

Tags: htaccess, joomla, no-www

Site is a Joomla 2.5 site. I wanted to add a non www to www redirect to the htaccess file, did so, then the redirection went mad, reversed but still the site redirects.

**When i click view site in admin panel, i get linked to `http://domain.comindex.php/`**

The website is `http://www.domain.com`
Visiting the website URL works without www, but once you click on projects it acts mad too.
Projects is managed with joomshopping extension.

EDIT: the redirect also happens when rewrite is deactivated in admin panel.

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.


Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php
Redirect 301 /services /project
Redirect 301 /projects/projects.html /project
Redirect 301 /projects/project1.html /project
Redirect 301 /projects/project2.html /project
Redirect 301 /projects /project
Redirect 301 /keypersonnel.html /about-agrin/keystaff
Redirect 301 /cooperation.htm /about-agrin/intcoop
Redirect 301 /member.html /about-agrin/memberships
Redirect 301 /contact.html /contacts
Redirect 301 /hr.htm /jobs
Redirect 301 /index.php/404 /index.php
```

Comment: added and removed a www to non www redirect, now its redirecting all to non www, but still the same error wit www.

It seems changes dont get adapted properly, this is really getting exciting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few conflicting rules and your 301's redirects should use absolute paths since this can cause loops, as well as a un-required index.htm > index.php which is also wrong and should be a conditional rewrite. Backup your htaccess file, and use the htaccess which is used on my site that I've edited to match your site.

```
#Joomla Defaults
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

#Removes index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.agrin-consult.com/ [R=301,L]

#Removes index.htm
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.htm\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://www.agrin-consult.com/ [R=301,L]

#Some Additional Rules
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

#Enforces WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.agrin-consult\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.agrin-consult.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Removes HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#Old Redirects
Redirect 301 /services http://www.agrin-consult.com/project
Redirect 301 /projects/projects.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/project
Redirect 301 /projects/project1.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/project
Redirect 301 /projects/project2.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/project
Redirect 301 /projects http://www.agrin-consult.com/project
Redirect 301 /keypersonnel.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/about-agrin/keystaff
Redirect 301 /cooperation.htm http://www.agrin-consult.com/about-agrin/intcoop
Redirect 301 /member.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/about-agrin/memberships
Redirect 301 /contact.html http://www.agrin-consult.com/contacts
Redirect 301 /hr.htm http://www.agrin-consult.com/jobs
```

**Ensure that you have the following Settings in your control panel**

1. Login to Administrator Control Panel in Joomla
2. Click Site Tab > Global Configuration
3. Search Engine Friendly URLs (Yes)
4. Use URL rewriting (Yes)
5. Adds Suffix to URL (No)

Comment: have uploaded you htaccess, no changes.
As it also beaves like this when i use the default htaccess where all was fine with maybe the problem is lying somewhere else?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ftp|mail)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: after the lines above where entered the mess started, i reversed it and now we are here.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled rewriting. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: it is enabled, your .htaccess is on the server. To make sure its enabled i disabled & renabled it.

Comment: Iam really not that much of a newb on joomla, but never experienced something similar. What i find most remarkable is that all this mess started after i edited the htaccess with the above mentioned redirect and it sutained till now even when i removed the entry and now uploaded your htaccess..

Comment: Again, the error sustains when mod rewrite is disabled too. The error also sustains when no htaccess is on the server.

Comment: Well it sounds mod_rewrite is not working on your server, make a blank .htaccess and add "I SHOULD NOT WORK" or any string so it pulls up a error 500... if you do not get a error 500 then mod_rewrite on your server is not working.  Is it shared hosting or vps/dedicated?

Comment: The error malfunciton dows not change whjatever i dot to the mod_rewrite settings or to htaccess.

Comment: Whoever worked on that site before i took over has left an old html site in the joomla directory, actually waiting for the site owner to clarify whts up with that.

Comment: The error resulted on 3 things.
1. malfunctionating htaccess
2. some files of anotehr website in the same directory
3. Browser problems on the working pc.

Its resolved now.